# Binding headers with hyphens to Play framework forms

Tags: java, spring, forms, data-binding, playframework

We authenticate some users of our web application via Shibboleth. The application is built using the Play framework. I want to bind the headers that come from Shibboleth to a Play form. According to the [the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaForms), data binding is performed using Spring.

Usually, binding just works. If you have a form model class like

```
public User {
    public String name;
}
```

then binding a form with a `name` field will match the two fields automatically.

One header that comes from Shibboleth is of the form `Shib-Identity-Provider`. I'd like to bind that to a field of my form model, but hyphens are not legal characters for field names in Java. Is there a way I can map the header name to a legal Java field name? This applies more generally too, can I configure the data binding so that I don't need to use identical form field names and Java class field names to get binding to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely create a class with different field names from the data binding.

For example you can create a `case class Shib` as follow:

```
case class Shib (provider: String)
```

and define the data binding function from the Play `mapping`

```
val formMapping = mapping(
   "Shib-Identity-Provider" -> text
)(Shib.apply)(Shib.unapply)
```

then in your controller you can bind the data directly from the request.
You can also implement a custom `Reads` which will doing a similar thing.

Comment: I wasn't clear in the original post, but I'm using Java, not Scala.

Comment: Well I'm sorry then :)